# Python console keeps asking for user input more times than coded for

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to learn functions and have created a little code `def` function to find out whether the measurements given will produce a right angled triangle. However whenever I try to run it, I am being asked the same question more than once.

The current code that I have produced is:

```
def is_rightangle():
    a=int(input("Enter a triangle length: "))
    b=int(input("Enter a triangle length: "))
    c=int(input("Enter a triangle length: "))

if (a*a + b*b == c*c or c*c + b*b == a*a or a*a + c*c == b*b):
    return True
else:
    return False

is_rightangle()
print (is_rightangle())
```

The console returns `Enter a triangle length:` 6 times instead of 3, a value for a, b, and c.

From what I can see I have not asked Python to ask the question more than 3 times, which is why I am confused.

Comment: You're calling `is_rightangle` twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write this:

```
is_rightangle()
print (is_rightangle())
```

You are doing two things. First, you call `is_rightangle()`, and that evaluates to either `True` or `False`. But, that value doesn't have any effect, and since the line is over, it goes to the next line. In the `print` statement, you are trying to print the value of `is_rightangle()` (which is being called for a second time, which is why you get six inputs instead of three).

What I would do is just remove the first call to `is_rightangle()`.

```
def is_rightangle():
    a=int(input("Enter a triangle length: "))
    b=int(input("Enter a triangle length: "))
    c=int(input("Enter a triangle length: "))

if (a*a + b*b == c*c or c*c + b*b == a*a or a*a + c*c == b*b):
    return True
else:
    return False

print (is_rightangle())
```